# GRE volume and SA related rate

Tags: calculus

So I have been asking some tougher related rates questions in prep for GRE subject, some members of this community are mean to me and vote to close my questions when I genuinely am benefitting from them, sort of not cool. On one post I stated I will delete the solution once completed as most members vote to close me anyways and one member said its a sin to close an answered question. Can you guys PLEASE NOT CLOSE THIS!! What else am I coming here for if I cannot get genuine help!? I am a student, is it a crime to not understand something? apparently here it is. It is sad for me to have to write this down and that members here have this sense of "dude you should know this already" attitude towards me. I can see if it is a repeat, but it was not even a repeat/duplicate. [image]

For this related rates, the wording of the surface area decreasing sort of confuses me. Any hints much appreciated! If $b$ is the base length and $h$ is height and $l$ is slang height, I know $V'=\frac{1}{3}(2bb'h+b^2h')$ and $S' = 2b(b'+l')$ and I found the slant height to be $50 \sqrt{5}$. Am I anywhere near close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface area of the pyramid is irrelevant. What is relevant is the volume of the remaining ice after $t$ hours which you can describe as a function $t$. To do so, I suggest you work with the projection of this pyramid onto a two dimensional plane.

The projection of this pyramid (before any ice melts) takes on a triangular shape which we may describe mathematically as the region bounded by the three curves: $$y=0:-50\leq x \leq 50 \\ y=2x+100:-50 \leq x \leq 0 \\ y=-2x+100:0\leq x \leq 50$$

After $t$ hours of melting this triangular projection shrinks into a smaller but similar triangular shaped region which we may describe mathematically as a region bounded by these three curves: $$y=t:-a(t) \leq x \leq a(t) \\ y=-2(x-a(t)) + t:0 \leq x \leq a(t) \\ y=2(x+a(t))+t:-a(t) \leq x \leq 0 $$ Here $a(t)=-\frac{t}{2}\big(1+\sqrt{5}\big)+50$. You can see this for yourself by clicking [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/73xq1tq1c7). The height $h(t)$ and the volume $V(t)$ after $t$ hours of melting equal $2a(t)$ and $\frac{8}{3}\big(a(t)\big)^3$ respectively. The height of the ice chunk is $10$ cm after $\frac{90}{1+\sqrt{5}}$ hours of melting so the rate of change in the volume at this point in time equals $$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg[\frac{8}{3}\big(a(t)\big)^3\Bigg]\Bigg|_{t=\frac{90}{1+\sqrt{5}}}=-100\big(1+\sqrt{5}\big)$$